# Hello_World not playing with mpi4pi on Cluster

Tags: python, mpi

I am trying to learn mpi4pi on the local cluster. I hence wrote a hello_world program, and it JUST WONT RUN! I have attached the .py code, and the .eer. Could someone point out what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

hello world:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
#import numpy as np
comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD
print "Hello, World! My rank is: " + str(comm.rank)
```

the error:

```
  File "MPI_Hello_World.py", line 4
print "Hello, World! My rank is: " + str(comm.rank)

                                 ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

File "MPI_Hello_World.py", line 4
    print "Hello, World! My rank is: " + str(comm.rank)
                                     ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "MPI_Hello_World.py", line 4
    print "Hello, World! My rank is: " + str(comm.rank)
                                     ^

```
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

File "MPI_Hello_World.py", line 4
    print "Hello, World! My rank is: " + str(comm.rank)
                                     ^

```
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

File "MPI_Hello_World.py", line 4
    print "Hello, World! My rank is: " + str(comm.rank)
                                     ^

```
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

File "MPI_Hello_World.py", line 4
    print "Hello, World! My rank is: " + str(comm.rank)
                                     ^

```
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using Python 3.x.

[`print`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function in Python 3.x.

```
>>> print "Hello, World! My rank is: " + str(1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "Hello, World! My rank is: " + str(1)
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print("Hello, World! My rank is: " + str(1))
Hello, World! My rank is: 1
```

Comment: It now generates the following error, after I fixed the function issue.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./MPI_Hello_World.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mpi4py import MPI
ImportError: libmpich.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @Sai, How about post another question with the exact traceback?

Comment: [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098651/hello-world-not-playing-with-mpi4pi-on-clusterii)