# Hello_World not playing with mpi4py on Cluster:II

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

Again, trying to learn mpi4py on the local cluster. I hence wrote a hello_world program, and it JUST WON'T RUN! I have attached the .py code, and the error. Could someone point out what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

hello world:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD
print("Hello, World! My rank is: " + str(comm.rank))
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./MPI_Hello_World.py", line 1, in <module>
 from mpi4py import MPI

ImportError: libmpich.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./MPI_Hello_World.py", line 1, in <module>
from mpi4py import MPI


ImportError: libmpich.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./MPI_Hello_World.py", line 1, in <module>
from mpi4py import MPI

ImportError: libmpich.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./MPI_Hello_World.py", line 1, in <module>
from mpi4py import MPI

ImportError: libmpich.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./MPI_Hello_World.py", line 1, in <module>
from mpi4py import MPI

ImportError: libmpich.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./MPI_Hello_World.py", line 1, in <module>
from mpi4py import MPI

ImportError: libmpich.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[See here for the part-I of the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097763/hello-world-not-playing-with-mpi4pi-on-cluster)

Comment: It appears to be an installation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not at all familiar with MPI4PY, but it looks like it requires a separate MPI installation as opposed to providing its own. Did you try installing one (MPICH, Open MPI, etc.) On most Linux systems, this is as easy as doing a quick

```
apt-get install mpich
```

Or whatever your flavor's package manager is. If you want the latest and greatest, you can get relatively simple instructions from the projects' websites:

MPICH: [www.mpich.org](http://www.mpich.org)

Open MPI: [wwww.open-mpi.org](http://www.open-mpi.org)